# How to create azure data explorer function which deletes data from table?

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am new to Azure data explorer and trying something like this

```
.create-or-alter function 
batchwise_last_processed_record_delete(){
.clear table batchwise_last_processed_record data;}
```

But I am getting below error

> A recognition error occurred.
> Token: .

Answer (score 1):

Please note the dot in the error message (right after "Token:")

> A recognition error occurred.
> Token: .

You cannot execute a command within a function